# class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Tags: c#, constructor

since I am trying to create new myshape, however there is a problem happened as the title mentioned, I did reasearch about this problems, but I have no idea how to fix it in my case. here is my class code

```
 public class Shape
    {
    private Color _color;
    private float _x, _y;
    private int _width, _height;
    private Point2D pt;

    public Shape(Color colors, float x, float y, int Width, int Height)
    {
        _color = colors;
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _width = Width;
        _height = Height;

        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        Width = 100;
        Height = 100;
        colors = Color.Green;
    }
```

and its how i did in the main

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        Shape myShape = new Shape();
        //Open the game window
        SwinGame.OpenGraphicsWindow("GameMain", 800, 600);
        SwinGame.ShowSwinGameSplashScreen();
```

and the error is "Mygame.shapes"does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

appreciated for any helps.

Comment: You created a constructor that takes a bunch of arguments, but you call a constructor without passing in any of those arguments.

Comment: Try `Shape myShape = new Shape(Color.Green, 0, 0, 100, 100);` -- also, why are you overriding all provided parameters in the constructor? Did you mean to create a *separate* constructor *without* any parameters and set default values?

Comment: I only paste a part of the code, it's not the full version.

Comment: @YunxiangLi - we can only work with the code you provided. And as it stands, it seems useless to even have a constructor with parameters, because it seems like you're overriding them anyway.

Comment: @Corak: The strangest thing about this is that he's overriding the arguments only after assigning their original values to the fields. So that second set of lines is useless, too. No idea what he's trying to accomplish here. Closing.

Comment: I am guessing between those two assignment blocks it's supposed to close the first constructor and open a second one with no arguments, that's the only way this code makes any sense. You say this is only part of the code, but then if there is another constructor that does take 0 arguments, you have a different problem, in what you posted there is only one constructor that takes 5 arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Shape` class only contains a constructor that accepts 5 arguments:
`public Shape(Color colors, float x, float y, int Width, int Height)`

So either call it explicitly from Main with the proper parameters, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Shape myShape = new Shape(Color.Green, x: 0, y: 0, Width: 10, Height: 10);
```

Or add a new constructor that sets default values:

```
public Shape()
{
    _color = Color.Green;
    _x = 0;
    _y = 0;
    _width = 100;
    _height = 100;
}
```

Comment: Or, (especially) if the constructor needs to do other stuff, too, you could have: `public Shape() : this(Color.Green, 0, 0, 100, 100) {}`. With all the logic in the constructor with the five arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to specify the parameters then you should provide default values in the constructor definition.

```
Optional variable-type variable-name=variable-value.
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx.

If default values are not provided then you must specify them when you create the object.

Or define a parameter less constructor as others have shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class, you can define 0, 1 or multiple constructors. Each one must have different signatures.

In case you are not defining a constructor in your class, a default one is defined behind the scene. This allow you to create an instance of this class by just writing (in your example):

```
Shape myShape = new Shape();
```

If you define a constructor in your class, once creating a new instance of this class, you must follow the signature of this constructor since the default constructor is now "gone away".
Meaning that in your case, you have a constructor that takes 5 arguments so you must call it once creating a new instance of your Shape:

```
Shape myShape = new Shape( [ all the 5 parameters]);
```

If you still want to construct your instance without passing any parameter, you must add the empty constructor explicitly and that's because you defined other constructors.

**So, in your case, you have 2 options:**

1.Add an empty constructor (in addition to the existing one):

```
public Shape()
{
    // here you will need to init your members with some default values        
}
```

2.Create your instance by calling the constructor with 5 parameters